# Building a contact in EOS Studio and getting eosio.code permissions when calling it

Tags: eosio-code, action, permissions

After deploying a contract built in EOS Studio ... on my call to another action where I have called 'permission_level()' ... I get a permission error
"transaction declares authority '{"actor":"grimdespair1","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions ***[{"actor":"grimdespair1","permission":"eosio.code"}]***,"

[image: This permission level method seems to be building an eosio.code permission into it]

OK - so I've learned that I need to set my eosio.code permission to allow me to do inline actions but I dont see where to do that in my EOS Studio even though the documentation says theres a tool to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

To do inline actions from within actions you have to SET EOSIO.CODE permission for your account - to do it on a network you make this call using CLEOS.

**cleos -u https://testnet.waxsweden.org set account permission  active --add-code**